# popper cant close when switching between toggle button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-popper

I am using the Material Ui Toggle button component, which have `Monthly` and `Weekly` two buttons.
Both using the same component, the `popper` will show only if the selected button is `weekly`.

My problem is when I open the popper in the weekly type, without close it, after that I choose `monthly`, the popper will show somewhere else in the page (not the same position that show in `weekly` type).

Not sure what's wrong with it.

Or make it like before swtiching to another button, close the popper?

Here's my code:

```
  <IconButton onClick={(event) => _handleOpenCalendar(event)}>
    <InsertInvitation />
  </IconButton>

  <Popper
    open={openCalendar}
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    modifiers={{
      flip: {
        enabled: true,
      },
    }}
  >
<Box sx={{ border: 1, p: 2, bgcolor: "background.paper" }}>
  <DateRangePicker
    inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
    startText="Start Date"
    endText="End Date"
    value={selectedDate?.[currentIdx]}
    onChange={(newValue) => _handleChangeDate(newValue)}
    maxDate={new Date()}
    renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <TextField {...startProps} helperText="" label="" />
        <DateRangeDelimiter> to </DateRangeDelimiter>
        <TextField {...endProps} helperText="" label="" />
      </React.Fragment>
    )}
  />
  <Box
    style={{
      marginTop: 5,
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "flex-end",
    }}
  >
    <Button
      variant="outlined"
      color="primary"
      onClick={_handleChangeDateCancel}
      style={{ marginRight: 5 }}
    >
      Cancel
    </Button>
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      onClick={_handleChangeDateOK}
    >
      OK
    </Button>
  </Box>
</Box>
```

```
const _handleChangeDateOK = () => {
    setOpenCalendar(false);
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };


const _handleChangeDateCancel = () => {
  setOpenCalendar(false);
  setAnchorEl(null);
  };

const _handleOpenCalendar = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    setOpenCalendar((previousOpen) => !previousOpen);
  };
```

Codesandbox url: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-grass-mg803l?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: provide a codesandbox it will be much clear

Comment: @monim hi, i have updated the question with codesandbox url. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**change  :**

```
const handleChangeType = (event, value) => {
    setType(value);
    
  };
```

**to :**

```
const handleChangeType = (event, value) => {
    setType(value);
    setOpenCalendar(false);
  };
```

By doing this change whenever you click the `ToggleButtons`  you'll update the `open` property to `false` so the Popper will not be shown.

Comment: no, i dont want the icon and popper appear when the `type === monthly`. but if when type === "weekly", and i open the popper without closing it, and i switch back to "monthly", the popper wont close.

Comment: sorry for answering late! I didn't get what you need first!  I updated my answer you can check if it's the desired behaviour